# Add Currency symbol in the y axis scale using plotly method in python

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to plot a bar chart using plotly and I wanted to add a currency "$" in the Y axis scale and also the Y axis figure should be delimited by "," (In Thousands, e.g, 1000 should be 1,000)

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go  

fig = go.Figure()       

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=["Apple", 'Mango', 'Banana'], y=[4000, 3000, 5000])) 

fig.show()
```

I expect to add a currency "$" in the Y axis scale and also the Y axis figure should be delimited by ",". (In Thousands, e.g, 1000 should be 1,000)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `fig.update_layout(yaxis_tickprefix = '$', yaxis_tickformat = ',.')`

If you want the cents after the decimal point, you can use `fig.update_layout(yaxis_tickprefix = '$', yaxis_tickformat = ',.2f')`

Comment: can you tell me how to add caption & subtitle as well. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: '$' works but no other currency symbol works, why?? any solution?? @nicolaskruchten

Comment: it works for me for any type of symbol actually.. `'€₼£฿د.ك'` works for example as a prefix

Comment: How to display -$10 and not $-10 for negative numbers?

Comment: @Warf I asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71303258/currency-tick-formatter-in-plotly-that-respects-negative-values on how to treat negative numbers correctly.