# $ tick formatter in Plotly that respects negative values

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

Per the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58142945/1840471) to [Add Currency symbol in the y axis scale using plotly method in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58140143/1840471), you can add a currency to a Python Plotly tick formatter via:

```py
fig.update_layout(yaxis_tickprefix = '$', yaxis_tickformat = ',.')
```

However, this shows negative numbers as `$-100` instead of `-$100`.

How can I format ticks to include $ and respect negative numbers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set the dollar sign in the tick format instead of the prefix, you will get the intended format.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(
    x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
    y = np.random.randint(-20,20,12)
))
fig.update_layout(yaxis_tickformat='$,')#yaxis_tickprefix='$',

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there some way to show GBP instead of USD? Tried setting Plotly locale config value to "en-GB" to no avail.

Comment: @N.Woodruff I filed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71311180/%c2%a3-tick-formatter-in-plotly-that-respects-negative-values for £