# £ tick formatter in Plotly that respects negative values

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

Is there a way to format ticks in Plotly with a £ prefix and the negative sign in the proper place?

`yaxis_tickformat='$,'` works for $:

```py
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.line(x=[1, 2], y=[3, -4])
fig.update_layout(yaxis_tickformat='$,')

fig.show()
```

[image]
But this is ignored for £:

```py
fig.update_layout(yaxis_tickformat='£,')

fig.show()
```

[image]
And using `tickprefix` puts the `-` in the wrong place:

```py
fig.update_layout(yaxis_tickprefix='£', yaxis_tickformat=',')

fig.show()
```

[image]
[Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/17rRkl4OW2icEkh8BUgiZ3CCYdcTTPoHq?usp=sharing) for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set locale config for Your axis and specify currency symbol.
All options are described [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/plot_api/plot_config.js).

So You can use `yaxis_tickformat='$,'`, but You have to change currency to £.

Here is working code:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.line(x=[1, 2], y=[3, -4])
fig.update_layout(yaxis_tickformat='$,')

config = {
          'locales': {
              'en': {
                'format': {'currency': ["£", ""]}}
              }
          }
fig.show(config=config)
```

Assuming Your locale is `en`.

Results in:
[image: plot]